# What does the y-axis "effect" mean after using gratia::draw for a GAM

Tags: effect, mgcv

I have made a GAM model using "mgcv" package with the `family = inverse.guassian(link = identity)` and I am really happy with the fit. After plotting the smooth terms using `gratia:draw(GAM, residuals = TRUE)` I am really confused by the y-axis. What does "effect" mean?

Any help would be very appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically this should read "Partial effect" (and I'll be fixing this shortly). This is the smooth effect of the covariate on the response conditional upon the other estimated terms.

Most smooths in {mgcv} are subject to a sum-to-zero identifiability constraint (so we can include an intercept in the model, which is especially useful when we have factor parametric terms in the model also), so they are centred about 0. The 0 line then means the overall mean (on the link scale) of the response (or the reference levels if factor parametric terms are involved in the model); negative values on the axis indicate where the effect of the covariate reduces the response below the average value, and positive values on the axis indicate those covariate values where the response is increased above the average. All conditional upon the other estimated model terms.

Comment: Hi @Gavin Simpson. Thank you so much for your response. So when the smoother term falls below negative the response variable (Y) is below average?

Comment: @Gavin Simpson, if the response variable is transformed, I suppose the interpretation of the y-axis is similar? And is there a way to plot the GAM in the original scale of the response variable?

Comment: @mtao yes, it's still a partial effect, but if you transform the partial effect, say back on to the response scale (by adding the model constant, and applying the inverse of the link function) then what you are seeing is literally the fitted smooth on the response scale while setting the effect of any other model terms to equal zero. As it is a purely additive model that's fine. Just remember that what is shown is conditional upon the other terms in the model - the estimate of the displayed smooth was arrived at with all the other model smooth, even if you ignore their effects when plotting

Comment: @mtao as to how to transform, see arguments `constant` and `fun` in `?draw.gam` or `?draw.smooth_estimates` for example and the functions `add_constant()` and `transform_fun()` for the functions that actually apply these transformations. I should also note that this isn't going to be right for factor by smooths for example.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thank you!! That clarifies some things, but I still have a couple more questions so I'll post them as a new question if that's ok!

Comment: @GavinSimpson here, if you could check it I would really appreciate it! Thank you very much for your help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75247151/interpretation-of-a-gam-plot-with-a-square-rooted-response-variable