# How to interpret the partial effect plots for parametric terms while using gratia::draw()?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv, parametric-equations, gratia

I am asking a question akin to this one: [What does the y-axis "effect" mean after using gratia::draw for a GAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71884457/what-does-the-y-axis-effect-mean-after-using-gratiadraw-for-a-gam) but am wondering the same question for parametric terms not smooths.

My data looks like this:

```
df<-structure(list(spreg = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("n", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    Landings = c(48974, 16933, 18389, 16433, 5720, 3775, 1388, 
    97109, 148609, 104267, 77454, 128938, 108096, 126957, 102396, 
    16165, 59423, 2892, 4728, 3783, 4785, 11359, 5323, 6106, 
    167, 568, 480, 2208, 4378, 1908), year = c(2007, 2009, 2011, 
    2013, 2015, 2018, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2012, 2015, 2018, 2007, 
    2007, 2012, 2015, 2018, 2008, 2010, 2006, 2008, 2011, 2008, 
    2011, 2007, 2010, 2007, 2014, 2015, 2014)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code looks like this:

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)
gam<-gam(Landings~s(year)+spreg,data=df)
draw(parametric_effects(gam))
```

Partial effect plot looks like this:

[image]

I want to report these partial effect plots for parametric terms but I am having trouble finding a good description of the partial effect plots for fixed effects. Is this the estimate and 95% credible interval like the smooth partial effect plots?

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for the `y` group is literally the estimated value for the `y` term shown in the output from `summary()` (or the estimated value for the coefficient labelled `spregy`), and the interval is based on the SE shown in that output too. The value for `n` is 0 as it is the reference level and hence it has 0 partial effect as the intercept term represents this group and the partial effects shown are for deviations from the intercept. I don't find these plots that useful, but `plot.gam()` showed them so `draw()` does as it is a ggplot-based alternative to `plot.gam()`.

The behaviour of `plot.gam()` and `draw()` follows (or closely follows) `termplot()`, with the former literally calling this function for plotting. If you want more useful outputs, packages *emmeans* or *marginaleffects* would be my go to options.